# Ошибка "NoneType" object has no attribute xxx в статическом методе

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-2.7

Писал приложение с использование `qt` под `python3`, но потом пришлось использовать `python 2.7` с которым возникла проблема: при закрытии окна приложения, когда отработал `sys.exit()` вылетает исключение.

> "NoneType" object has no attribute

[Вот](http://pastebin.com/nAt6K0UB) пример реализации класса, с которым у меня проблема

```
class myClass(object):
    watcher = None

    @staticmethod
    def launch():
        th = Thread(target = myClass.watcherThread, name = "myClass watcher thread")
        th.daemon = True
        th.start()
        myClass.watcher = th

    @staticmethod
    def stop():
        myClass.watcher = None  

    @staticmethod
    def watcherThread():
        while(true):

        #some code

            if(myClass.watcher == None):
                break
```

В данном случае ошибка возникает на строчке

```
myClass.watcher == None
```

почему же подобная ошибка возникает в статическом методе?

**Update:**
полный пример ошибки

> Exception in thread joystick input listener (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
>
> File "/home/user/python/nes2/libs/input.py", line 43, in   joystickInputListener
>
> type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'callback'

Comment: приведите полное сообщение об ошибке (вместе с traceback)

Comment: вся информация, необходимая для ответа, должна быть в самом вопросе приведена (не используйте внешние ресурсы). Нажмите кнопку [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/485820/edit) и добавьте информацию в сам вопрос.

Comment: Судя по коду ошибки, она возникает совсем не на той строчке. Можете привести полный код?

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, т.к. ошибка возникла не в том коде, который приведен в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое решение но я его не сильно гарантирую. Суть в том что в python есть команда `try` и `except:` который грубо говоря "тупо" удаляет ошибку. Это пишется так:

```
try:                                                                                                         
    #пишешь то в где сомневаешься может быть ошибка                                                        
except:
    pass # или то что будет делать когда будет ошибка
```